# What does the bonus on a potion mean?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, potions

I couldn't find it anywhere, can someone help me understand what [potion bonus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm) in D&D 3.5 actually means? For example I can find in the example potions [Shield of Faith](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shieldOfFaith.htm) +2.

It says:

> This spell creates a shimmering, magical field around the touched creature that averts attacks. The spell grants the subject a +2 deflection bonus to AC, with an additional +1 to the bonus for every six levels you have (maximum +5 deflection bonus at 18th level).

Does it mean it gives another +2 deflection bonus to AC (so it gives +4) and +2 to the bonus for every six levels? (instead of +1)? Where should I apply this bonus given in the name to the potion effect?

Please forgive me if I haven't noticed it anywhere in the book or SRD, but I've  tried to find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The potion bonus simply refers to how much you add to whatever statistic the related spell increases. So a "Potion of Shield of Faith (+2)" gives you a +2 Deflection bonus to AC, since that's the statistic Shield of Faith enhances.

It's written like that so it's easier and shorter than "Potion of Shield of Faith (caster level 1)" and then making the reader look up in the Shield of Faith spell what that will actually do.

You can deduce from the cost that the better potions are made at a higher caster level. (the +2 version costs 50gp, which means it's "1st level spell x caster level 1 x 50gp", while the +3 version costs 300gp, which means it's "1st level spell x caster level 6 x 50gp", and 6th level is where it starts granting the +3 bonus)

Comment: Thank you very much, so the name already includes a total amount of bonus added? And what about this additional +1 bonus for every six levels, does it also influence it in any way or just the basic +2 deflection bonus and the last part remain as in spell description?

Comment: Does it mean that Potion of Shield of Faith (+3) is like it was simply cast at level 6 caster level? So it gives its basic +2 and +1 for six levels?

Comment: @Bloodlex yep, the +3 version simply means it's a caster level 6 potion of the same spell, the (+3) just helps you see what the main bonus will be. It also means that the duration on the +3 version is 6 minutes, for example.